# Rails with Angularjs on reloading the page , the content rendered from angularjs disappears

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I am using Rails with Angularjs . So, i have link called "Notes" and when i click "Note" it takes me to url "http://localhost:3000/#/notes" and renders some templates through angularjs. 
When i reload the page , the templates didn't reload and when i click the link "Note" again then only it renders those templates.

So my simple question is On reloading the page , why all the contents that is rendered through angularjs disappears and how to fix this.

**Updated**

```
-javascript
   -index.html
   -routes.js

-view
   -course
      -index.html
```

view/course/index.html

```
<div class="row">
  <div ng-include="'index.html'"></div>
</div>
```

javascript/index.html

```
<div class="nav-list">
  <a ui-sref="notes"> Notes </a>
  <a ui-sref="users"> Users </a>
</div>

<div class="main-wrapper">
  <ui-view></ui-view>
</div>
```

javescript/routes.js

```
....
    .state('notes', {
      url: '/notes',
      templateUrl: 'template/pages/notes/index.html',
      controller: 'NotesIndexController'
    })
    .state('users', {
      url: '/users',
      templateUrl: 'template/pages/users/index.html'
    })
...
```

I changed the above scenario to this

view/course/index.html

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="nav-list">
      <a ui-sref="notes"> Notes </a>
      <a ui-sref="users"> Users </a>
    </div>

    <div class="hero-wrapper">
      <div class="hero-content">
        <div class="hero"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="main-wrapper">
      <ui-view></ui-view>
    </div>
</div>
```

This fixed my problem but what is the difference between above two scenarios . Why it is behaving differently . Thanks

Comment: pls see if there are any error in console of a browser

Answer (score 2):

You need to troubleshoot each piece of your application separately. You don't have a "Rails and AngularJS" problem; you have either a problem with your Rails API (which is serving up JSON to Angular) or you have a problem with your Angular client (which is receiving proper data from your API but isn't displaying it properly) -- or both.

I'd start at the Rails side; use an API testing tool like Cocoa Rest Client to simulate requests to the Rails API and ensure the response data is in the format you'd expect. Once you've verified that, you've reduced this from a maybe-also-Rails problem to a pure Angular problem, and you can troubleshoot the Angular app in isolation (eg. by feeding it dummy JSON instead of having it talk to the Rails app).

Good luck!

Comment: i fixed my problem and updates the question. Can you explain me why it is happening?